# How to limit for loop to print first few element from list in python?

Tags: python

How should i print the first 5 element from list using for loop in python. i created some thing is here.

```
x= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
for x in x:
   print x;
```

with this it just print all elements within list.but i wanted to print first 5 element from list.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use slicing:

```
for i in x[:5]:
    print i
```

This will get the first five elements of a list, which you then iterate through and print each item.

It's also not recommended to do `for x in x:`, as you have just overwritten the list itself.

Finally, semi-colons aren't needed in python :).

Comment: And this won't raise any `IndexError` if list contains fewer items.

Comment: Alternatively - for much larger slices than 5 elements - use `itertools.islice` to avoid constructing a large temporary sublist. But it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper [Slicing is faster than `islice`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048698/efficient-iteration-over-slice-in-python) in almost all cases.

Comment: Actully what i wanted know is. I read the records from mongodb in one variable with test = collectionname.fetch() and i wanted to print first few records from this all records in html did like                                                               {{ %for i in test }} //perform other operation on i so instead of this way is there any other way With this loop operation is performed on all records.

Comment: @hcwhsa - thanks for the link, I'll have to remember that. I guess `islice` is mostly better for slicing non-list iterables like other generator expressions.

Comment: @VivekBhintade I'm not familiar with that type of syntax, sorry

Comment: @VivekBhintade If you're using django, then django templates also support slicing: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#slice

Comment: @VivekBhintade - can you add more detail regarding exactly what your data source is to your question? The slicing answer is correct for lists, which is what your question currently refers to.