# How to rewrite the code which appends to lists with numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064822/how-to-add-items-into-a-numpy-array) is mentioned that appending to numpy array is not an good idea because it requires re-allocation of the array memory and it slows down the code. There are also mentioned some hints how to avoid it. My goal is to create an saw signal, something like this ASCII art: `/\/\/\/\`. I've end up with following two codes and I do not know which one is worse. 2nd one uses also `itertools.islice` which is also not world's speed recorder as it discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048698/efficient-iteration-over-slice-in-python). Both codes mixes standard python lists and numpy arrays. Is there a way how can achieve the same but using pure numpy arrays? Or better: is there any general rule which I can use with numpy everywhere where I would use `list.append` instead? As I said on 1st page are mentioned some hints but I cannot figure out working solution. I've been thinking about something like list comprehension that will allow me expand the `saw` array first which then I could pass to `np.hstack` but I do not think this is possible. I've been also thinking about first declaring numpy array with `numpy.empty(400)` or `np.zeros(400)` but I do not know how to properly assign to them further values and seems that `np.empty` is not so completely empty because it contains zero values:

```
In [106]: x = np.zeros(10)
In [107]: x
Out[107]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

In [108]: y = np.empty(10)
In [109]: y
Out[109]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

1st

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

saw = []
for x in xrange(0, 3):
  saw.append(np.hstack((np.linspace(0,1,50), np.linspace(1,0,50))))
saw2 = saw[0]
for x in saw:
  saw2 = np.append([saw2], [x])
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(saw2.size), saw2)
plt.show()
```

2nd

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

saw = []
for x in xrange(0, 4):
  saw.append(np.hstack((np.linspace(0,1,50), np.linspace(1,0,50))))
saw2 = saw[0]
for x in islice(saw, 1, None, 1):
  saw2 = np.append([saw2], [x])
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.arange(saw2.size), saw2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You might try doing some performance testing to find out what is really most efficient.  Some things worth testing are insert at the beginning vs at the end vs append vs contatenate.  Some results are at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133885/fastest-way-to-grow-a-numpy-numeric-array.

Comment: Generally - work out the size of your array first. Then allocate an array of this size with, say, `np.zeros` or `np.empty`. Then assign the results to the appropriate slice of the array, e.g. `saw[start_index:end_index] = ...`

Comment: Thanks for tips guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2 iterations are only of size 3.  That's to construct an array that is `(400,)`.  That kind of iteration isn't something to worry about much.

I can clean up your code by writing it as:

```
xup=np.linspace(0,1,50)
xdn=np.linspace(1,0,50)
x=np.hstack([xup,xdn])
saw2 = np.hstack([x for _ in range(4)])
```

The list comprehension is just your `saw`.

`np.stack` (or `np.concatenate`) takes a list (or lists or arrays), so there's no need to iterate through the list, doing a concatenate item by item.  `np.append` is just a pairwise concatenate:

```
 np.append(saw2,x) == np.concatenate([saw2,x])
```

It's even simpler to use `np.tile` to replicate `x`

```
saw2 = np.tile(x,4)
```

or something a bit faster  (`tile` uses repeat in a similar way)

```
saw2 = x[None,:].repeat(4,0).flatten()
```

Comment: Thank you for valuable hints