# Is there O(1) space O(k) running time way to create and use an iterator over a k-size slice in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Since the accepted answer for a similar question [Efficient iteration over slice in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048698/efficient-iteration-over-slice-in-python) does not offer O(1) running time, I am creating a separate question here.

Let's say we have a list l of size n, and a slice of size k << n that starts in a middle (n/2).

It is very trivial to iterate in a for-in loop optimally:

```
for i in range(n//2,n//2+k)
  #do something with l[i] 
  ...
```

However my goal is to create an iterator over the slice using standard python tools, so i could use that iterator later on for chaining, filtering, and subslicing using itertools.

Couple standard options are not really good:

`iter(l[n//2:n//2+k])`  will actually use O(k) extra space for a copy

`itertools.islice(l, n//2, n//2+k)` will use O(1) space, but O(n) extra running time to reach the slice range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own:

```
def turbo_slice(iterable, start, stop, step=1):
    for ii in range(start, stop, step):
        yield iterable[ii]
```

Or if you prefer:

```
def turbo_slice(iterable, start, stop, step=1):
    return map(iterable.__getitem__, range(start, stop, step))
```

Then:

```
for item in turbo_slice(l, n/2, n/2+k):
    # do something with item
```

I tested the performance of both implementations, they're about the same (if you must know, the first is 8% faster which surprised me a little).

Comment: Seems too verbose having to define a generator function every time you need it. Feels like should be part of itertools. If there is no really other way of doing it using builtin python modules, i will accept this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I am posting this as an improvement on top of the accepted answer.
Apparently, there is a more concise way of doing this called generator expressions:

```
(l[i] for i in range(n//2,n//2+k))
```

The expression above return a generator which can serve as an efficient iterator, and can be combined with itertools.